# String comparison of 'content' property read from <div> element by JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, comparison, trim

I am only asking this, because I am really confused about this and even trimming doesn't help getting this comparison pass.

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#someDiv {
    content: "someValue";
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value = $("#someDiv").css("content");
    value = $.trim(value);
    console.log(value);


    if (value == "someValue") {
        console.log("good");
    }
    else {
        console.log("bad");   
    }


});
```

Why does the string comparison fail here?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/srLhpps9/4/)

EDIT: The strange thing that got me confused was that this comparison was OK in Chrome/Chromium but not in Firefox.

Comment: What outputs `console.log(value);`?

Comment: ""someValue"" just as the fiddle' console shows.

Comment: `"someValue"` != `someValue`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing quotes and double quotes in the beginning and end of content? Maybe adding something like this after trimming?
`value = value.replace(/^(\"|\')|(\"|\')$/g, "");`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2v6asvpc/) (Works on both Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Apparently, it was the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Value has single quotes included, literally, change the if to

```
if (value == "'someValue'")
```

to pass,

or add this after trim and keep the if as is

```
value=value.replace(/'/g,'');
```

or change the if to

```
if (eval(value) == "someValue")
```

Comment: console.log says: "bad"

Comment: Not for me. What is your browser? Mine is Firefox 38.0 for Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, it's OK on Chromium, but not on Firefox.

Comment: Good in chrome. But you should make use of  `===`

Comment: @brroshan I have changed the code to ===  comparison, still fails on Firefox.

Comment: How should I debug? It's either if or else.

Comment: How about `if (/someValue/.test(value))`

Comment: @DrunkenMaster In my FF console, `console.log(value);` outputs `"value"` and not `'value'` as on Chrome. So it seems quite easy to fix. Now that's why i asked if at least you check your console in FF?!